# How can I get a stack trace when running Qt5 applications in a debugger?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, cmake, qt5

I'm compiling my Qt program with `-g -O0` options to get debug symbols. I then run it in `lldb`and it crashes in *my* code, not the library. But the backtrace I'm getting looks like this:

```
Target 0: (mastercontrol) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff5c27f2c2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff5c33abf1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 284
    frame #2: 0x00007fff5c1e96a6 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00007fff593c4641 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 231
    frame #4: 0x00007fff593c47c7 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 243
    frame #5: 0x00007fff5a977eeb libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 105
    frame #6: 0x00007fff593d019e libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x00007fff593c3c7e libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #8: 0x00007fff5a975e35 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #9: 0x00007fff301a05ec CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 609
    frame #10: 0x00007fff2f3ff1ab HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    frame #11: 0x00007fff2f3feee5 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 603
    frame #12: 0x00007fff2f3fec76 HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
    frame #13: 0x00007fff2d79677d AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 1135
    frame #14: 0x00007fff2d79546b AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
    frame #15: 0x00007fff2d78f588 AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 699
    frame #16: 0x000000012264033c libqcocoa.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_symbol693$$libqcocoa.dylib + 2652
    frame #17: 0x0000000108a9b75f QtCore`QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 431
    frame #18: 0x0000000108a9fb62 QtCore`QCoreApplication::exec() + 130
    frame #19: 0x000000010001b20d mastercontrol`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbfe2a0) at master_control.cpp:108:10
    frame #20: 0x00007fff5c1443d5 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

I.e. the actual site of the crash, which is inside my own code somewhere does not show up.

How do I need to configure my CMake build to get an actual stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

The exception was caught and rethrown in `CoreFoundation::CFRunLoopRunSpecific`, not in QT.

You have to run the application under a debugger with first-chance-exception enabled in order to break when the exception is thrown first, rather than breaking when it's left uncaught last.

In `gdb`, that should be `catch throw` for enabling breakpoint on exception. In `lldb` use `break set -E c++`.

Comment: Life saved. gdb seems like a hassle to set up on osx, but the equivalent for LLDB works. I assume this will break on any exception thrown, even if I catch it in my own code, correct?